# Is it safe to remove "Google app" from android system completely?

Tags: root-access, bloatware

I rooted my device and I removed some obvious bloat-ware, such as Cardio trainer (I bike to work, I definitely do not need that), some Google music, Google books, Google maps and many other Google XXX and Samsung XXX consumer applications.

Now, in second purge iteration, I'm looking at apps that are big but their purpose is not obviously blatant.

One of them is "Google app". The name isn't very informative. Does it manage my link between android and Google account? Or is it some search service? What is that app and what are the consequences of deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can iff the Google app has the ["G" logo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en), it is just a search app. I am on a custom ROM, Cyanogen Mod 13 and it doesn't come with bloatwares or Google apps.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed Google App on several Orignal stock ROMs without any problems. It provides a Search Bar and some other functionality which is not required for their other apps to function (Maps, Gmail, Store etc). It's a resource hog. I think in the future they will make it harder to remove it by making it integral part of their framework, but for now it's ok to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove various Google apps, but you should refrain from uninstalling Android System Webview. Once you do that, Google setting, Gmail etc. will stop working.